# element.className not updating DOM immediately

Tags: css, classname

I'm developing an app on various Smart TV platforms and one of the older platforms uses an old version of the Maple browser.

Unique to this browser seems to be that setting element.className does not seem to automatically update the DOM eg if I remove a class from an element then immediately call document.getElementsByClassName(class), that original element still appears in the list of elements with that class.

example:

```
// when entering here, "menu0" has className "focusedmenu" so clear it
var el = document.getElementById("menu0");
el.className = "";

// as a sanity check, get all elements with class "focusedmenu"
var focused = document.getElementsByClassName("focusedmenu");
for (var i = 0; i < focused.length; i++) {
    // 'menu0' will still show as having 'focusedmenu' class
    alert ( "focusedmenu id " + focused[i].getAttribute('id') );
}
```

This code seems to work fine on other platforms so I'm guessing I either need to take a different approach or somehow force the DOM to refresh as soon as I modify className.

Can anyone recommend a good solution?

Comment: Can we see the HTML markup? the only way I can see this behavior happening is if you have more then one element with the `id='menu0'`